# How to expand $\mathbf{r}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})$

Tags: matrices

I need to expand:

$$\mathbf{r}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})$$

I believe that $\mathbf{AB}\neq\mathbf{BA}$, $\mathbf{AA}^{-1}=1$, and that $(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T=(\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{A} ^T \mathbf{x}^T)$

but I am not really sure how to go about the expansion, in particular I worry about the fact that  $\mathbf{AB}\neq\mathbf{BA}$.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})=
\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}=\\
\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}\quad(\textrm{if}\quad \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}^T)$$

Answer (score 0):

First note that (as $(\mathbf{AB})^T=\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A}^T$) we have
$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T=(\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T)$$

Thus, to expand $\mathbf{r}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})$, the following operations need to be carried out:-
$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})=(\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T)\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})\\=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Ax}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Ax}\\=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}\\=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}\\=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1})\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}$$
where we assume that $\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}$ is a scalar, so that it will equal $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}$.